# Java Android No more background processes

Tags: java, android

I want to understand some things that take place in JAVA application while application is loading. First of all then I launch my application it start to load more then 180MB of libraries to the RAM of the phone and I can see

> 12-12 19:05:05.478: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12579): GC_EXPLICIT freed 53K, 48% free 3513K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 471ms
>   12-12 19:05:22.181: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Process com.google.android.apps.maps (pid 12875) has died.
>   12-12 19:05:22.181: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Low Memory: No more background processes.
>   12-12 19:05:23.814: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Process com.android.launcher (pid 12563) has died.
>   12-12 19:05:23.857: INFO/WindowManager(115): WIN DEATH: Window{407fcdf8 SurfaceView paused=false}
>   12-12 19:05:23.931: INFO/WindowManager(115): WIN DEATH: Window{407dacf8 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher paused=false}
>   12-12 19:05:23.931: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Low Memory: No more background processes.

such logs in my LogCat, some processes ***has died***.

I want to know the meaning of this messages

- ***Low Memory: No more background processes.***
- ***Process com.android.launcher (pid 12563) has died.***

Why this processes died and how I can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First of all then I launch my application it start to load more then 180MB of libraries to the RAM
>   INFO/ActivityManager(115): Low Memory: No more background processes. 12-12 19:05:23.814:
>   INFO/ActivityManager(115): Process com.android.launcher (pid 12563) has died

180MB of libraries is WAY too much. Most devices have around 256-512mb ram. How much does yours have? A lot of that ram is used just to operate the device normally.

The process died because the OS needed to free up memory and chose it to kill. If you want this app to run, you're going to have to trim some of the fat.

Comment: +1, if your application needs 180MB of libraries, that's a problem in the first place. What are these libraries??

Comment: If you cant find a way to trim them, maybe you can fire the work off to some server.

Comment: @TomDignan I have .jar library which is written not by me and I use that library in order to do some actions with voice, the size of library is 176 MB. I can't use other library, Now I want to understand what can I do ?

Comment: @TomDignan Okay I understand finally that I can't do anything as all jar files are load to memory and as I have jar that is 176 MB all other applications will die. Thanks for answer !!! ACCEPTED :)

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan sorry, wasn't around. Yeah, all you can do is scratch the jar. Probably write a backend and access the jar over the web.

Answer (score 0):

They are killed by the system in order to free up memory to try and satisfy your applications requirements. It's generally a bad idea to cause such instability in the system, so if possible, don't load 180 MB of libraries into RAM.